# OpenCV speed up Mat iteration

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to iterate throug a 3 channel Matrix in the HSV color space and it's awfully slow. It takes about 2.5 sec.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread( "image.jpg" );
cv::Mat img32FC3;

img.convertTo( img32FC3, CV_32FC3 );
cv::cvtColor( img32FC3, img32FC3, CV_BGR2HSV );
int height = img32FC3.rows;
int width = img32FC3.cols;
cv::Size size = img32FC3.size();
if( img32FC3.isContinuous() ) {
  size.width *= size.height;
  size.height = 1;
}
size.width *= 3;
for( int i = 0; i < size.height; i ++ ) {
    float* ptr = img32FC3.ptr<float>(i);

    for( int j = 0; j < size.width; j += 3 ) {
        h = (ptr[ j ]);
        s = (ptr[j +1 ]);
        v = (ptr[j +2 ]);
    }
}

cv::cvtColor( img32FC3, img32FC3, CV_HSV2BGR );
img32FC3.convertTo( img, CV_8UC3 );
imwrite("test.jpg", img );
```

The code above is adapted from the [documentation of openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#Mat%3a%3aisContinuous) where it states that it's performant. So I wonder how I can speed this up because 2.5 sec is really very very slow :(.

BTW: the image is 3744x5616 pixel

Comment: Have you profiled it? Where does it take the most time? What is the intended purpose of those 2 for loops? IMO they do nothing.

Comment: Are you measuring the whole thing? What about those `cv::imread('...')` and `imwrite`? It should take some time to read/write and compress/decompress JPEG for big images like these.

Comment: Yes you are right, the for loop does not do anything (at the moment). I inted to calculate some things... - Now I have profiled it - you are right, reading and writing needs 1.2 sec and the for loop itself takes 0.6 sec... Is it possible to speed the loop up or is it the best I can do?

Comment: Do you really need floating point matrices? If not, try to use another type. I presume it will be much faster...

Comment: Yes I thougt so, too but I need the full 360° of the H channel. And in CV_8UC3 I have only 180° according to the documentation...

Comment: On Windows in VC++2010 you can do it in parallel using parallel_for from PPL. See How to: Write a parallel_for Loop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728073.aspx)

Comment: @Maecky what about using  CV_16UC3 then ?

Comment: Ok thanks, I will have a look into PPL. @Quentin Geissmann, according to the documentation of OpenCV are 16 Bit images not supported for HSV conversion. So it's either 8 Bit with loss of the colors or 32Bit...

Comment: ok, I did not know, thank you:)

Comment: The 0.6 second for the loop seems to be reasonable considering image size `3744x5616`, 32 bits and 3 channels per pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best chance to speed up is to parallelize the loop. OpenCV uses TBB as multithreading environment, you might want to check it. By the way, you dont need to do all your calculations about the size, etc. You already checked that your matrix isContinuous(), so you can get the pointer as `float ptr = reinterpret_cast<float>(img32FC3.data)` then your loop:

```
for (size_t i = ; i < img32FC3.rows*img32FC3.cols; ++i, ptr +=3) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This ptr += 3 could indicate bad practice, probably because the refman does not explain color images. There we use Vec3b (maybe in this special case Vec3f) as a type instead of <double>.

Answer (score 3):

You should not directly access the data of a mat since sometimes it is not stored as you would expect. Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860599/why-does-assertion-fail-here/13187395#13187395).

Another way is using the Mat iterator. According to the  [opencv_tutorials.pdf, ver 2.4.2 pp. 89-92]
it is slightly slower than the nested loops from my link. (For a large image you are 5% slower but note that they used just MatIterator, not the *const* one which can be further optimised by a nice compiler.)

```
MatConstIterator_<Vec3b> it = M.begin<Vec3b>(), it_end = M.end<Vec3b>();
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
{ 
  //do sth read-only otherwise use MatIterator_<Vec3b>
  b = (*it)[0]; 
  g = (*it)[1]; 
  r = (*it)[2]; 
}
```

`<double>` if grayscale, from ocv2.4.2 refman p19.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm a little bit confused now. I checked your other answer and there you stated that according to the manual the most efficient way is to access a matrix row first and then iterate through the cols. In the code above, you use MatConstIterator_ ... From my gut, I would go with the MatConstIterator, but I think it's time to compare these two methods to determine which is the fastest ;)

Comment: I was wrong, corrected my answer, I hope it helped... if it did, can you please indicate? ;) Im interested in your performance tests, too! ;)

Comment: There are situations, where keeping a row and column count is essential. How will that be possible when iterating using MatIterator or MatConstIterator?